# How to find Queue Priority number?

Tags: apex, soql, queue

Is there a way to query Queue priority? and I know you can find the Queue via soql:

```
select Id from Group where Name = 'my group' and type = 'Queue'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, you have to do this in two queries. First, get the QueueRoutingConfigId field:

```
Group[] groups = [select QueueRoutingConfigId from Group where Type='Queue'];
Set<Id> routingConfigIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Group record: groups) {
    routingConfigIds.add(record.QueueRoutingConfigId);
}
```

Then query for the routing configs:

```
Map<Id,QueueRoutingConfig> configs = new Map<Id,QueueRoutingConfig>(
    [select RoutingPriority from QueueRoutingConfig where Id = :routingConfigIds]
);
```